# Javascript and radio_button in rails - status checked only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I try to put radio buttons for my images. When user click on one image, other radio buttons should have checked set to false. Right now i have something like this:

```
$('.image_choose').each( function() {

    $(this).click(function() {

            $('.image_choose').each( function() {
                $(this).attr("style","border:1px solid #e5e5e5");
                $(this).attr("id","in_active");
                $inputs = $(this).find('input[type="radio"]');
                $inputs.attr("checked", false);
            });
                 $label = $(this), $input = $(this).find('input[type="radio"]');
         $label.find('input').attr("checked", true); 
            });
     });
```

Rails:

```
<% @array_new.each do |a|%>
    <div class='image_containter'>
        <li class='image_choose'>       
        <%= f.radio_button :image_url ,a %>

                    </li>
            </div>
    <% end %>
```

So as i think - when user click on image_choose element, first for every image_choose i set attr and checked to false. And then change it to true for $this element. What is wrong in here? Only when first time click on image, radio_button change graph and status.

SOME SOLUTION :

I dont think its good way to do this but i found that:

```
$label.find('input').prop("checked", true); 
$label.find('input').attr("checked", true);
```

when i do this - it start working like it should. Only .prop does not set input checked='checked', and only .attr does not change radio button value on second click... i dont understand what is wrong in here.

Comment: Could you add html source or can you create an example at jsfiddle?

Comment: in html every input that i click have status "checked" and for other inputs checked is removed. But still radio button isnt "checked", graph of it isnt "checked" -  and my script also doesnt see it as checked.

Comment: can somebody help with that? What is wrong in this script? Only first click on each image_choose change radio_button. In firebug i see that checkec='checked' but event that, radio_button isnt checked.

Comment: Why it is so hard to provide more html source code? An individual problem needs an individual solution.

Comment: You wont help soo what does this change? I put tag for rails soo mayby this is problem in rails but you removed it.

Comment: Jquery runs on client side, so it is obvisly a problem with the generated html output. Ruby runs on server side.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to deal with Javascript to work with radiobuttons in this way.

To make things easier, use an actual HTML `<label>` tag for each radiobutton in your list. When clicking anywhere in that label, the radiobutton will be triggered. Just make sure you properly link the label to the radiobutton by its ID.

Also, make sure your radiobutton IDs are always unique. The `name` attribute of all your radiobuttons needs to be identical, so the browser knows that they are a radiobutton group.

Use this ERB (adapt if not 100% correct):

```
<% @image_urls.each do |img| %>
    <%= f.label :image_url, img_tag(img) %>
    <%= f.radio_button :image_url, img %>
<% end %>
```

The result should look something like this:

```
<label for="image_url_your_img_val1">
    <img src="yourimage1.png"/>
</label>
<input type="radio" name="image_url" id="image_url_your_img_val1" value="your_img_val1"/>

<label for="image_url_your_img_val2">
    <img src="yourimage2.png"/>
</label>
<input type="radio" name="image_url" id="image_url_your_img_val2" value="your_img_val2" />
```